# Переключатель между Activity

Tags: android, java

Ввёл следующее в **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnActTwo;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
    btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnActTwo:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // TODO Call second activity
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText("Tab1");
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tab);

    tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText("Tab2");
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tab);

}

}
```

При запуске приложения вывод ошибку:

```
Error:(52, 8) error: duplicate class: startandroid.ru.myschool.MainActivity
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знание англосаксонского хотя бы на базовом уровне очень сильно помогает в программировании.

В данном случае компилятор ругается на классы с одинаковым именем в одном пакете. Так нельзя. Переименуйте один из них и подумайте зачем вам вообще их два. Проще переключаться меж разными отображениями в одном классе активити.